# How to add data into join table from form in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have three models in my rails application. When I create a new notification how do I rewrite the notifications_controller.rb and the form in notifications/new.html.erb so that the entry gets saved to the notifications_users table? Thanks

schema.rb

```
create_table "notifications", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "title"
 t.string "first_name"
 t.string "last_name"
 t.datetime "date"
 t.text "content"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false

 end

create_table "notifications_users", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
 t.bigint "user_id", null: false
 t.bigint "notification_id", null: false
 end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "first_name"
 t.string "last_name"
 t.string "user_type"
 t.string "username"
 t.string "password"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 t.string "password_digest"
 t.index ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true

end
```

new.html.erb

```
<h1>New Message</h1>

 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

 <%= form_for(@notification, url: notifications_new_path) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>


  <%= f.label :first_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :date %>
  <%= f.datetime_field :date %>

  <%= f.label :content %>
  <%= f.text_area :content, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.submit "Create my message", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

notifications_controller.rb

```
def create
  @notification = Notification.new(notification_params)    

  if @notification.save
    flash[:success] = "Notification created!"
    redirect_to @notification 
 else
   render 'new'
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to create two records here, a `Notification` record and a `NotificationUser` record. There are a number of ways to do this such as:

```
...
@notification = Notification.new(notification_params)    

if @notification.save
  NotificationUser.create(user_id: USER_ID_HERE, notification_id: @notification.id) # OR NotificationUser.create(user: USER_RECORD_HERE, notification: @notification) OR @notification.users << USER_RECORD_HERE
...
```